# Navigation bar -- links don't work

Tags: html, css

On the navigation bar, the link only works if I hover over the **TEXT** however it doesnt work if I hover underneath or above the text (between the 1 px horizontal lines and the text) here is a link to the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hp20wcrd/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.menu {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial; 
    position:fixed; 
    background:transparent;
    width:100%; 
    top:100px; 
    left:0; 
    height:25px;       /* decide on this as some stage */
    padding: 0;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;  /* decide on this as some stage */
    padding-top: 10px;  /* decide on this as some stage */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.ty-menu__items {
    position: absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.ty-menu__item {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    }

a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: light;
    color: #494949;
    background: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:hover, a:active {
    padding-bottom:7px;  /* decide on this as some stage */
    background: transparent;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #9B9B9B; /* decide on this as some stage */
    color: #9B9B9B; /* decide on this as some stage */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="menu">
<ul class="ty-menu__items">
  <li class="ty-menu__item"><a href="#home">home</a></li>
  <li class="ty-menu__item"><a href="#news">news</a></li>
  <li class="ty-menu__item"><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
  <li class="ty-menu__item"><a href="#about">about</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Move the padding to the link rather than the `li`?

Comment: add some width to `.ty-menu__item`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (your `a` is not all clickable, you must create vertical full clickable on your `a` using `padding`)

**CSS**

```
.menu {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial; 
    position:fixed; 
    background:transparent;
    width:100%; 
    top:100px; 
    left:0; 
    height:35px;       /* decide on this as some stage */
    padding: 0;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;  /* decide on this as some stage */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.ty-menu__items {
    position: absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.ty-menu__item {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    }

a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: light;
    color: #494949;
    background: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 10px 0px;
}

a:hover, a:active {
    padding-bottom:7px;  /* decide on this as some stage */
    background: transparent;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #9B9B9B; /* decide on this as some stage */
    color: #9B9B9B; /* decide on this as some stage */
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hp20wcrd/6/)**

Answer (score 3):

You can add `padding` in `a` element instead:

```css
.menu {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial;
  position: fixed;
  background: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  /* decide on this as some stage */
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  /* decide on this as some stage */
  /* decide on this as some stage */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.ty-menu__items {
  position: absolute;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.ty-menu__item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
a:link,
a:visited {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: light;
  color: #494949;
  background: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-top: 10px;/*add padding top*/
  padding-bottom: 10px;/*add padding bottom*/
}
a:hover,
a:active {
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  /* decide on this as some stage */
  background: transparent;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #9B9B9B;
  /* decide on this as some stage */
  color: #9B9B9B;
  /* decide on this as some stage */
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="ty-menu__items">
    <li class="ty-menu__item"><a href="#home">home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ty-menu__item"><a href="#news">news</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ty-menu__item"><a href="#contact">contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ty-menu__item"><a href="#about">about</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you gave padding to the ul element and its parent, not the actual anchor, which is the "clickable" area. Something like this should work (with removing the extra padding on the ul element):

```
.ty-menu__item a {
    padding: 8px 0 6px;
}
```

See it here:

```css
.menu {
 font-family: Verdana, Arial; 
    position:fixed; 
    background:transparent;
    width:100%; 
    top:100px; 
    left:0; 
    height:32px;       /* decide on this as some stage */
    padding: 0;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;  /* decide on this as some stage */
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.ty-menu__items {
    position: absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.ty-menu__item {
    display: inline-block;
 padding-right: 50px;
 padding-left: 50px;
 }

.ty-menu__item a {
    padding: 8px 0 6px;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: light;
    color: #494949;
    background: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:hover, a:active {
    padding-bottom:7px;  /* decide on this as some stage */
    background: transparent;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #9B9B9B; /* decide on this as some stage */
    color: #9B9B9B; /* decide on this as some stage */
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
<ul class="ty-menu__items">
  <li class="ty-menu__item"><a href="#home">home</a></li>
  <li class="ty-menu__item"><a href="#news">news</a></li>
  <li class="ty-menu__item"><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
  <li class="ty-menu__item"><a href="#about">about</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hp20wcrd/14/

Answer (score 0):

Put the padding on the a tags, and let those take up the space. The li tags will simply take the size of the a tags.

I put together this jsfiddle (I commented out what wasn't needed): http://jsfiddle.net/g5o9dun9/

```
.menu {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial; 
    position:fixed; 
    background:transparent;
    width:100%; 
    top:100px; 
    left:0; 
 /*   height:25px; */      /* decide on this as some stage */
    padding: 0;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;  /* decide on this as some stage */
/*  padding-top: 10px; */ /* decide on this as some stage */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.ty-menu__items {
    /* position: absolute; */
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* width:100%; */
    text-align: center;
}

.ty-menu__item {
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0px 50px;
  }

.ty-menu__item a{
    padding:20px
}

a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: light;
    color: #494949;
    background: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:hover, a:active {
    padding-bottom:7px;  /* decide on this as some stage */
    background: transparent;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #9B9B9B; /* decide on this as some stage */
    color: #9B9B9B; /* decide on this as some stage */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added padding for the anchor tag and dropped the padding-top on .menu

edit:  i also added padding-bottom to the .menu to match your hover selector

```
.menu {
font-family: Verdana, Arial; 
position:fixed; 
background:transparent;
width:100%; 
top:100px; 
left:0; 
height:25px;       /* decide on this as some stage */
padding: 0;
text-align:center;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: 600;  /* decide on this as some stage */
padding-bottom:7px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.ty-menu__items {
position: absolute;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
width:100%;
text-align: center;
}

.ty-menu__item {
display: inline-block;
padding-right: 50px;
padding-left: 50px;
}

a:link, a:visited {
display: block;
width: 100%;
font-weight: light;
color: #494949;
background: transparent;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
a {
padding:7px 0px;
}
a:hover, a:active {
background: transparent;
border-bottom: 3px solid #9B9B9B; /* decide on this as some stage */
color: #9B9B9B; /* decide on this as some stage */
}
```